# How to convert a json string saved in mysql database to php JSON Object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an issue with converting a string in json format to json object in php.
I am saving a json string into database using ajax save. I want to convert the string into json for doing further operation. I used json_decode but with no help.

JSON STRING IN MYSQL DATABASE:

```
"{\"title\":\"Sachin vs shoaib akhtar and company..Unseen (BAAP BAAP HI HOTA HAI ) ....flv\",\"titleEsc\":\"Sachin vs shoaib akhtar and company..Unseen (BAAP BAAP HI HOTA HAI ) ....flv\",\"url\":\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOJlDpoL7tw\",\"pageUrl\":\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOJlDpoL7tw\",\"cannonicalUrl\":\"www.youtube.com\",\"description\":\"Sachin hitting cluless shoaib akhtar and company everywhere in ground..This is one f many innings where shoaib akhtar was brutually assaulted by sachin tendu...\",\"descriptionEsc\":\"Sachin hitting cluless shoaib akhtar and company everywhere in ground..This is one f many innings where shoaib akhtar was brutually assaulted by sachin tendu...\",\"images\":\"http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/WOJlDpoL7tw/hqdefault.jpg\",\"video\":\"yes\",\"videoIframe\":\"<iframe id=\\\"20131122120255WOJlDpoL7tw\\\" style=\\\"display: none; margin-bottom: 5px;\\\" width=\\\"499\\\" height=\\\"368\\\" src=\\\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/WOJlDpoL7tw\\\" frameborder=\\\"0\\\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\"}"
```

I am getting this field through mysql select. What i want to do is convert the string into JSON Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) like,

```
$array=json_decode($yourjson,true);
var_dump($array);
```

For `Object`

```
$object=json_decode($yourjson);
var_dump($object);
```

Comment: thanks Rohan that did the trick.But when i tried this without assigning to a variable like $array it was not showing strange... anyway fast reply...really appreciate buddy!! :)